# How to programmatically trigger validation of an input bsDatepicker?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

There's a [bug](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5286) in bsDatepicker, I don't know if this bug has been patched in recent ngx-bootstap versions but due to [compatibility](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap#compatibility) reasons with my current Angular version 4.4.6 I won't be able to upgrade my ngx-bootstrap version 2.0.2 to the most recent version. Therefore I want to find a way to programatically trigger the validation of the following input components when some event is fired :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <label>{{'project_date_start'|translate}}</label>
    <div class="input-container">
      <i class="far fa-hourglass-start icon"></i>
      <input type="text" class="datepicker-input datepicker-border" autocomplete="off" name="dateStart"
        [(ngModel)]="project.dateStart"
        [minDate]="getMinStartDate(project.dateEnd)"
        placeholder="{{'project_date_start'| translate}}" bsDatepicker #dateStart="bsDatepicker"
        [required]="true" [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'}"
        (ngModelChange)="reset($event)">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <label>{{'project_date_end'|translate}}</label>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" class="datepicker-input datepicker-border" autocomplete="off" name="dateEnd"
        [(ngModel)]="project.dateEnd"
        [bsValue]="project.dateEnd"
        [minDate]="getMinEndDate(project.dateStart)"
        [required]="true" placeholder="{{'project_date_end'| translate}}" 
        bsDatepicker #dateEnd="bsDatepicker" [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'}" 
        (ngModelChange)="reset($event)">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this please?

Comment: What event fires? When the event fires? What should it re-validate? Anyway, looks like `project` holds all the data. You could reload properties to trigger Agular's change detection with spread e.g `project = { ...project }`

Comment: @JoosepParts could you please provide a link to some code snippet? As for the event i meant by that a change event in one of the two inputs above, after which both `project.dateStart` and `project.dateEnd` will be re-validated.